# Simple JSON to HTML Table

Tags: jquery, json

I have a very simple data that i want to display in table.

DATA

[{"1":"Red","2":"Orange","3":"Blue","4":"Yellow"}]

CODE:

```
 var a = [];
                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                        a.push('<tr id="tr_' +key+ '">');
                        a.push('<td>' + key+ '</td>');
                        a.push('<td>' + val+ '</td>');
                        a.push('</tr>');
                    });
                    var s = a.join('');
                    $('#color-list').html(s);
```

The above code resulted in [object Object] instead of the Data.

Below is my expected result

1    Red

2    Orange

3    Blue

4    Yellow

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You may very well use a dedicated jQuery plugin to populate data from JSON to HTML https://github.com/anuary/jquery-json-to-table. You are playing with raw HTML, rather than DOM. Which isn't really practical or safe. Since you already using jQuery you might just learn to use `.text()` and `.html()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data variable is an array (containing only one element). The object is actually the first element of that array. So use:

```
$.each(data[0], function (key, val) {
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is an array of 1 value which is an object. If you loop through the array you'll get one row in your table with that object as the value.

Instead you should remove the [] and have just the object and then go through the keys/values of that instead:

```
var data = {"1":"Red","2":"Orange","3":"Blue","4":"Yellow"}
```

This then gives the result you want.

If you can't get rid of the [ ] for some reason (e.g. external data source) then just use data[0] in your loop instead of data to get the object from the first position in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop around in this way:

```
 // If the returned data is an object do nothing, else try to parse
var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    str += '<tr>';
    for (var index in array[i]) {
        str += '<td>' + array[i] + '</td><td>' + array[i][index] + '</td>';
    }
    str += '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually Sometimes it doesnt works when json is in string form. Please try the following:

`[{"Srno":38,"ReqId":36,"ItemId":155,"Qty":90.00,"TransferItemId":null,"TransferQty":null,"ExpReqDated":"\/Date(1363285800000)\/","IsCancelled":false,"Remarks":null},d":171,"Qty":40.00,"TransferItemId":null,"TransferQty":null,"ExpReqDated":"\/Date(1363717800000)\/","IsCancelled":false,"Remarks":null},{"Srno":113,"ReqId":53,"ItemId":172,"Qty":40.00,"TransferItemId":null,"TransferQty":null,"ExpReqDated":"\/Date(1363717800000)\/","IsCancelled":false,"Remarks":null}]"`

Then We have cast json by JSON.parse(data) to convert it in array...